# I refractored com.example in my Android app. Now, getting Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, xml, gradient, runtimeexception

I completed my app, uploaded it to the Google Play Console and realized I couldn't use the com.example.myherocalc package. So, I refractored it to myherometa.myherocalc and got a bunch of errors. The ones that are persisting seem to be suggesting the Main Activity can't access my resources?

```
    Process: myherometa.myherocalc, PID: 11754
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myherometa.myherocalc/myherometa.myherocalc.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24 in myherometa.myherocalc:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #24 in myherometa.myherocalc:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24 in myherometa.myherocalc:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #24 in myherometa.myherocalc:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24 in myherometa.myherocalc:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable myherometa.myherocalc:drawable/opp_life_background with resource ID #0x7f0800a1
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/opp_life_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800a1
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:891)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:673)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:993)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1006)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:981)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5535)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:990)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:102)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:97)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1563)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
2022-05-23 22:10:22.144 11754-11754/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at myherometa.myherocalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Class not found gradient
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:224)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:141)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1402)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1391)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:199)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:126)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:144)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1402)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1361)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:954)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:877)
            ... 43 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "gradient" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/myherometa.myherocalc/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~b5t9FhNkIi2_o23GW_3SZw==/myherometa.myherocalc-F42q7jj-JxM1PYvRaXmlQQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~b5t9FhNkIi2_o23GW_3SZw==/myherometa.myherocalc-F42q7jj-JxM1PYvRaXmlQQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:205)
            ... 53 more
```

MainActivity.java (It's 300 lines, so I'll just include the OnCreate)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public int startOppLife, startSelfLife, oppLife, selfLife, atkSpeed, atkDamage, target, zone, diesRolling;
    public TextView txtOppLife, txtSelfLife, txtSpeed, txtDamage, txtSettOppLife, txtSettSelfLife;
    public Button btnOppLife, btnSelfLife;
    public ImageView imgSpeed;
    public ImageButton btnReset, btnDieRoll;
    public String lifeSlip;
    public Random rng;


   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Set Life Variables
        startOppLife = 25;
        oppLife = 25;
        startSelfLife = 25;
        selfLife = 25;
        atkSpeed = 4;
        atkDamage = 4;
        target = 0;
        zone = 2;
        rng = new Random();
        rng.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setMainViewButtons();
    }
```

opp_life_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#221111"
                android:centerColor="#881111"
                android:startColor="#221111"
                android:angle="90"/>
            <corners android:radius="15dip" />
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#000000" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#331111"
                android:centerColor="#ff1111"
                android:startColor="#991111"
                android:angle="90"/>
            <corners android:radius="15dip" />
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#000000" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Try changing the package name in build.grade and rebuild

Comment: I tried. I'm getting the same error. I Cleaned, Rebuild, changed the package name, everything similar I could think of.

Comment: After playing around with it. I see the problem is my .xml files are the problem. The ones that are using ```<selector> <item android:state_pressed="true">``` are not working. They were working before the refractor. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see the syntax
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList